# Load localhost image to use with Algorithmia

Tags: python

I am trying to use this api: [ImageSimilarity](https://algorithmia.com/algorithms/zskurultay/ImageSimilarity) with the Python endpoint.

Any ideas on how to load local images in the API? The example shows:

```
[  "data://zskurultay/ImageDemo/butterfly1.png",
"data://zskurultay/ImageDemo/butterfly1.png"]
```

Yet when I pass as input1 a local image for example with:`data://home/username/path/to/image.png` yelds the error:

```
Exception: algorithmia.api.APIException: Unexpected API response, status 400,
url http://172.17.42.1:4160/v1/data/home/username/path/to/image.png:
{"error":{"message":"Path invalid"}}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs

Comment: @RishavKundu tried, but there is now the error: apply() functions do not match input data

Answer (score 1):

data:// is for Algorithmia cloud images. (You can create your own bucket in their cloud.) To access my local images I try to use different code like,

```
algo = client.algo( '... alg name ....')
image = base64.b64encode( open( infile, "rb").read())
image_alg = algo.pipe( {'image':'data:image/jpg;base64,' + image.decode('ascii')})
return image_alg.result
```

But I am still searching for the right tools.